# Using the new Bing API (nodejs)

Tags: api, node.js

I am trying to switch over to the new bing search api which is now hosted on azure and as most of you know that the `Appid` parameter has been removed for authentication, I can't figure out an easy way to get the results of the query.

I am using `http` module for nodejs and the current code uses `http.get` to query the `api.bing.net`
.

Can someone show me the code to use the new one correctly?

I tried this, but the url fails to return anything 
http://gavinmhackeling.com/blog/2012/05/using-the-bing-search-api-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there was a typo in my blog post.

Make sure that you are using your default account key from https://datamarket.azure.com/account/keys.

To use the basic authentication, replace `<YourDefaultAccountKey>` in `https://user:<YourDefaultAccountKey>@api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?Query=%27leo%20fender%27&Market=%27en-US%27&$top=50&$format=JSON`. You will be returned results in JSON.

You can also use https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/explore/5BA839F1-12CE-4CCE-BF57-A49D98D29A44 to test query parameters and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-bing-api) that encapsulates the requests, so you can use it like:

```
var Bing = require('node-bing-api')({ accKey: "your-account-key" });

Bing.web("stack overflow", function(error, res, body){
    console.log(body);
  },
  {
    top: 50,
    market: 'en-US'
  });
```

It works with the Azure version. You only have to replace your account key.